# RT2800 USB: monitor mode using Virtual Box

Tags: virtualization, wireless-networking, kali-linux

### Information

I am using a WiFi USB Adapter and the latest version of Kali running under VirtualBox.

```
Chipset: Ralink RT2870/3070
Driver: rt2800usb
Manufacturer: TP-Link
FCC ID: TE7WN727NV3
```

It is supposed to support monitor mode and packet injection: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Rt2800usb

lsusb returns:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
```

lsmod returns:

```
usbcore, rt2800usb, rt2x00usb, rt2800lib, rt2x00lib, mac80211, cfg80211, crc_ccitt and rfkill.
```

As I said, I'm using the latest version of Kali, so it should have the drivers already installed. The version of VirtualBox is 4.3.12.

### Problem

It seems that the adapter is being detected and enabled by VirtualBox:
[image: WiFi USB Adapter enabled]

And it seems to work in normal mode: 
[image: It works in normal mode]

However, when I try to setup the monitor mode, it doesn't seem to be able to detect any AP: 
[image: Monitor mode enabled]

[image: Not any AP detected.]

### Question

What is going on? Why It is not able to find any AP?

Comment: Boot under native Kali and see if the problem persists, to rule out any VM-related issue. And really, don't complicate your life with a VM, just install Linux natively, anyway you'll have to do it if you need to do any serious pentesting.

Comment: @AndréDaniel I used to install Linux natively, but I need a lot of VMs because I need one different environment for each different project I do.

Comment: @AndréDaniel USB adapters through a VM work well like this.  I use them regularly.  There are plenty of reasons why a VM is much more convenient.

Comment: @Brad What setting should I use to use? Would you need more information?

Comment: What do `ifconfig` and `iwconfig` show about this adapter when You switch to _Monitor mode_?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that VirtualBox has some issues when virtualizing USB 3.0 and that's why it didn't work for me. Other alternatives for virtualization worked fine.